# I Need to get a Datepicker Value from a Child Component and use it in an onClick in the Parent

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular site with routing and forms that is connected to a local database. I have an API set up to connect to this database and using forms I can pull data fro this database; currently I want to be able to use two separate DatePickers and use them as a Date range for the DB search. I have a child component set-up that includes a single DatePicker and then it is called twice in the parent Component with the Form. The Child Component looks like this:

**date-range.component.html**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input  class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" [name]="name" 
         placeholder="From date" value="" [(ngModel)]="model" 
         #dp="ngbDatepicker" ngbDatepicker>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar mb-2 mr-sm-2" (click)="dp.toggle()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**date-range.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-range',
  templateUrl: './date-range.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-range.component.css']
})
export class DateRangeComponent {

  @Input() model: Date;
  @Output() dateModel = new EventEmitter<Date>();
  

  constructor() { }

  onChange() {
    this.dateModel.emit(this.model);
  }

  }
```

Visual Studio is showing no errors here. the Component is called in the Parent as below:

**product-list.component.html**

```
<app-date-range name="dp1" (dateModel)="dateModel($event)" [model]="model"
                    #productFromDate>

</app-date-range>
<app-date-range name="dp2" (dateModel)="dateModel($event)" [model]="model"
                    #productToDate>

    </app-date-range>
    
    <button (click)=
"searchProducts(productFromDate.value, productToDate.value);" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
```

While the TypeScript looks like this:

**product-list.component.ts**

```
 export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    
    model: Date = null;
    
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this is the default search that is ran on page load
    this.searchProducts('', '', '', '10');
  }
    dateModel(date: Date) {
        this.model = date;
      }
    
    }
```

My Problem is that even though I have tried multiple ways of doing this, I can't seem to find one that gets the date value from the Child DatePickers into a format that I can use in my search method such as `productFromDate.value`

Any suggestions or even a point in the right direction would be appreciated! I've only been using Angular for about 3 weeks, so still learning stuff.

**Update:**

I've re-done the whole thing with the Angular Material Date-Picker and got it working using MatDatepickerInputEvent

Comment: A bit confused here about what you are looking out for, are you unable to get the date value from the child component? Or you are able to get the value from the child component but the format is not correct?

Comment: Tbh, I don't know if I am getting it correctly, I can see any way to event print out the value to see if it is correct. So I want the value from the datepickers and I want to be able to pass them as arguements to the `searchProducts` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem that I can see here is you have not implemented OnChanges in your DateRangeComponent class.

```
export class Date RangeComponent implements OnChanges
```

Secondly, you need to implement the ngOnChanges function:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // your logic here
}
```

If you want to display the values, you can use console.log and check how the values are changing.